# Word. Page numbering and section breaks

Tags: ms-office

Mac Word 14.5.3. Page numbering. I inserted page numbers when first starting this document. 
I then inserted several section breaks (next page) in my document so I could change page orientation. On these pages the numbering has been lost. 
However, it's continued numbering several page breaks down but with a random number.
How do I get the page numbering to continue smoothly all the way through the document, Section breaks and all?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by 
1) double clicking in the footer
2) going to the design tab that pops up
3) in the header and footer section of that tab clicking on the page number style that looks like the one that was showing up everywhere else in the document.

I did this and the number was correct because it was already linked to previous page.

FYI, if you don't know what style page number you have going on throughout the rest of your doc, you can't copy/paste the format of a page number you have on another page. Tried it, failed, worked around it.